# Why Entity Framework Core one to many relationship creates only left join?. IsRequired is not working

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, one-to-many

I decided to use Entity Framework Core  for my Web API. I have a problem with one to many relationship.
Let's say we have `Person` and `PersonAddress` entities. The entities related as one to many relation.

```
public class Person
{
  public int Id { get; set;}
  public string Name { get; set;}
  
  //Navigation property
  public ICollection<PersonAddress> Addresses { get; set;}
}

public class PersonAddress
{
  public int Id { get; set;}
  public string Street { get; set;}
  public int PersonId { get; set;}
  
  //Navigation property
  public Person Person {get;set;}
}
```

And I configurated the entities in `DbContext OnModelCreating` method as following

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
  modelBuilder.Entity<PersonAddress>()
                .HasOne(x => x.Person)
                .WithMany(x => x.PersonAddresses)
                .IsRequired(true)
                .HasForeignKey(x => x.PersonId);
}
```

Problem is that when I try to get `Person` inclueded `PersonAddress` entityframework created query with **left join**. But I want to create with **inner join**.
My code and query is like that:

```
 var result = _dbContext.Persons.
                .Include(x => x.PersonAddresses)
                .ToList();

SELECT `l`.`*
FROM `Person` AS `l`
LEFT JOIN 
`PersonAddresses` AS `l0`
 ON `l`.`Id` = `t`.`PersonId`
```

I tried a lot of way to solve the problem but it was not solved. Does anyone faced the problem? How can I solve it?

**I use Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 5.0.5 version**

Comment: That's not how `.Include` works.  `Persons` already contains `Person` objects without addresses, before you use `.Include`.

Comment: Since it appears that you know how to write SQL, have you considered just using a raw query?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql

Comment: Or using Linq to exclude those `Person` objects that don't have an address?

Comment: @RobertHarvey I can add another `where` to my linq query to solve the problem. Bu I want to know why it is not working. I added   `IsRequired` in `OnModelCreating` . Also `PersonId` propery is not nulluble in `PersonAddress` entity

Comment: `IsRequired` doesn't do what you think it does.  `PersonID` doesn't have to be non-null if there's no address record.

Comment: `PersonId` is in `PersonAddress `. It means that if address has `PersonId` has to be. `PersonId` is foreignKey

Comment: It means that, if you have a `PersonAddress` object, it must contain a `PersonID`.  It doesn't mean that the entire address is required.  If you don't have a `PersonAddress` object, there's no place to store a `PersonID`.

Comment: That would have been nice to know 28 minutes ago.

Comment: u can put a tag on that foreign key Like ```[Required]```. its the same logic . if the foreign key is not nullable and required, the relationship is gonna be ```Required```. as a second suggestion : if u wanna create inner join,u better use ```Where()```  u can look at that link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/eager#filtered-include

Comment: There is no way this to work in EF6 or *any* ORM, since it is relational database concept - the *many* side is always optional - the 0 (zero) part in the notation 1 to 0..N

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Entity Framework created query with **left join**.

It's fundamental to the relational database concept. There's no way to enforce by database constraints that a `Person` has at least one `PersonAddress`. (Unless you want to reverse the association for one address, but that's a different story having its own issues).

Neither does the mapping API have any formal instructions to map a 1:1..n relationship, which would required client-side validation when saving data.

The only thing EF can do is: simply return what you ask. You ask `_dbContext.Persons` so you get them all. The `Include` doesn't tell that you only want persons with addresses. It tells that you want all persons with their addresses (0..n) included.

> How can I solve it?

1. by adding a predicate:

```
_dbContext.Persons.
    .Where(p => p.PersonAddresses.Any())
    .Include(x => x.PersonAddresses)
    .ToList()
```

Which gets the correct data by `OUTER JOIN` + `WHERE` but is inferior to an inner join.

2. Manually write an inner join and group in memory

```cs
    var result = (
        from p in _dbContext.Persons
        join pa in _dbContext.Addresses on p.Id equals pa.PersonId
        select new { p, pa }
    ).AsEnumerable()
    .GroupBy(r => r.p)
    .Select(r => r.Key);
```

This creates a query with inner join as you want, but of course it's quite a hassle. The switch to memory (or client-side evaluation) is necessary because EF can't translate the `GroupBy`.

This question made me coin an `IncludeInner` method as [EF feature request](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/24955).